# What happens if a user does not mark the question as solved?

Tags: support, users, unanswered-questions

I've seen some questions lately on superuser, which get many answers, but the user who did the question does not mark the question as solved. When I say solved I mean when the user accepts an answer as the best one. Do this questions stay on the unanswered category? Or do they get marked as solved automatically after a couple of days or months?
I was getting curious, since in many questions I've answered some users comment they solved the problem (and do not mark the question as solved), or they do not return to the question to give updates if the problem is solved or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marking an answer as accepted is purely optional and the mark is never set automatically.

A question is treated as "answered" once an answer was marked as accepted or when any other receives an upvote.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "has a positive score"? +1/-1 doesn't count as answered IIRC.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Actually, I'm not sure. Feel free to edit if you're certain.